# “Script_name” is not generated after making a .rs file (in android source code)

Tags: java, android

I need to generate in Android source code,
I have seen this directory that has been generated (this is Galaxy4 in android source code).
"\out\target\common\obj\APPS\Galaxy4_intermediates\src\renderscript\src\com\android\galaxy4"
I need to be generated in SystemUI.Thanks!

This is what I already have:

```
Android.mk > LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) \ src/com/android/systemui/EventLogTags.logtags $(prev_compiled_rs_files) LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_TARGET_API := 18 LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_COMPATIBILITY := 18 LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_FLAGS := -rs-package-name=android.support.v8.renderscript prev_compiled_rs_files := $(call all-renderscript-files-under, src)
```

Comment: Can you share what you've already done, if anything? SO isn't a "write your code for you" site.

Comment: Android.mk

> 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
    src/com/android/systemui/EventLogTags.logtags
    $(prev_compiled_rs_files)

LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_TARGET_API := 18

LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_COMPATIBILITY := 18

LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_FLAGS := -rs-package-name=android.support.v8.renderscript
prev_compiled_rs_files := $(call all-renderscript-files-under, src)